# Google assistant SDK doesn't read my mails

Tags: python-3.x, gmail-api, google-assistant-sdk

I've built a smartmirror which does almost everything but when I ask it to read my mails then I can get an output stating that "I don't have permission to read your mails" How do i solve this issue?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a permission issue. Check out the activity controls:

https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/troubleshooting#permissions